# How to make Open / Save dialogues stay in same folder in OS X?

Tags: macos, finder

OS X's open and save dialogues have a very detailed way of remembering (or forgetting, depends on how you see it) the directory you're working in. I have the impression it is saved individually for each app and dialogue type.

A use case: we have a file `my/akward/long/path/logos/logo.ai` which we want to convert to a png and then upload it to a website.

- Illustrator: Open Dialogue: Browse to `my/akward/long/path/logos/`.
- Illustrator: Save for web - Save Dialogue: We're somewhere else
  (where we last exported to), browse to `my/akward/long/path/logos/`
  again, save the png.
- Chrome: Upload button, Open dialogue: Oh no,
  again, we're where we last uploaded from. Browse to
  `my/akward/long/path/logos/` and upload the png.

I find this constant directory browsing extremely tedious.

I just want all Save, Open and possible other dialogues of all Apps to stay in the same directory. Until I change to another directory, then stay there.

Is that possible? Maybe with an extra app?

Comment: In a standard file picker you can drag your intended location from Finder to picker. For more advanced options, try Default Folder X - stclair software (on phone so no link, sorry)

Comment: Super! It's http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/release.html . I've also found a workaround: make a smart folder (http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/smart-folders-and-os-x-yosemite.html) that only displays folders used in the last day or so, then add it to the sidebar. Still one click more though. I will try the app